# Laravel CLI Custom Package without Registering Manual to config/app.php

Tags: php, laravel, package

I just created a simple Laravel CLI package in Laravel 8. My custom command doesn't appear in `php artisan list` and the provider needs to register manually into `config/app.php` to make it work. As far as I know, we don't need to register the provider manually in Laravel 5.5+.

Here is my provider source code:

```
<?php

namespace Robyfirnandoyusuf\BadOmen;

use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Robyfirnandoyusuf\BadOmen\Commands\Migrate;

class BadOmenServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->commands([
                Migrate::class
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function register()
    {
        
    }
}
```

and this is the structure of the directories:

[image]

Anyone have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**, by adding *providers* property in the package's composer.json file, with a value of [Robyfirnandoyusuf\BadOmen\BadOmenServiceProvider::class]